# Removing duplicate strings/words(not lines) using RegEx(notepad++)

Tags: regex, string, text, notepad++

I would like to know a way to remove duplicate words or strings in a text file(not lines) using notepad++ regex find tool.

I only saw ways to remove duplicate lines using TextFx and that is not what i am looking for.

Example -

123 / 789
123 / 321

Removing 123 would result in

123 / 789
 / 321

Comment: So what exactly *are*  you looking for? Do you mean duplicates like `"It's the the mailman!"` (duplicate `the`) or `"The cat chased the dog"` (duplicate `the` with intervening words) , or `"banana"` (duplicate `na`)? Or something else?

Comment: Use this RE **\b(\w+)(?:\s+\1\b)+**
Courtesy of [StackExchange][1] 


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/454046/how-to-remove-all-the-duplicated-words-on-every-line-using-notepad

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with Notepad++, but assuming it uses standard syntax, replace

```
\b(\w+)\b([\w\W]*)\b\1\b
```

with

```
$1$2
```

Comment: There is no lookahead in your code. You probably mean backreference.

Comment: Oops. Thanks. It was late. In fact I meant to offer a lookahead-based solution, but then I remembered reading somewhere that NPP doesn't support lookaheads, wrote a different solution, and forgot to change the description.