# Remove duplicated strings within Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, duplicates

I was trying to find a way to remove duplicated strings within Notepad++ (not removing duplicated lines). For example, if I have the text:

Alice's favorite ice cream (not gelato) is: Vanilla! Alice's favorite ice cream (not gelato) is: Vanilla! Please go get some ice cream from the store

The result should be

Alice's favorite ice cream (not gelato) is: Vanilla! Please go get some ice cream from the store

I tried looking up some examples and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302308/removing-duplicate-strings-wordsnot-lines-using-regexnotepad) but it doesn't really work exactly as expected. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you identify what is a duplicated string? is it always a line that contains the duplicate?

Comment: Basically every line has a duplicated string, but rather than manually going through and deleting the duplicated portions of the string I would like to automate it somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have consecutive duplicates then you can use a regex like this:

```
(.*)\1
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/iG5eA7/1)**

And use the replacemente string: `\1` or `$1` as you can see in the `substitution section` in the screenshot.

[image]

**Update**: as **[1010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4020264/1010)** pointed in this comment:

> beware that it may match duplicates like the 'o' in "look", or parts of a sentence that repeats characters as in "... this is a duplicate"

You can prevent this by creating a limitation for minimal duplicated chars. For instance, this regex looks for duplicated chars that will have at least 5 duplicated characters (you can modify the numbere for what you consider right):

```
(.{5,})\1
```

Comment: In Notepad++ 6.7.5 this just gives me the message "Zero length match" and no changes are made to the file.

Comment: @AdrianHHH I'm using 5.9.6 and works fine for me. I'll try updating the version

Comment: beware that it may match duplicates like the 'o' in "look", or parts of a sentence that repeats characters as in "... th**is is** a duplicate".

Comment: @1010 Thanks, for the comment. I improved the answer thanks to you

Comment: @Fede Is there any way to accommodate the case where words with double letter would be after the duplicated text? For example:  
`Alice's favorite ice cream (not gelato) is: Vanilla! Alice's favorite ice cream (not gelato) is: Vanilla! Please go get some ice cream from the store, and hurry!` would be changed to `Alice's favorite ice cream (not gelato) is: Vanilla! Please go get some ice cream from the store, and hury!`

Comment: @aholtz sorry, i'm not following you

Comment: with Fede's update you can limit the minimum number of characters of a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem and wanted to remove duplicate lines. It turns out that there is already a built-in feature to do that.

Just go to "Edit->Line Operations->Remove Consecutive Duplicate Lines".