# Notepad++ Regex to find string on a line and remove duplicates of the exact string

Tags: regex, duplicates, notepad++

Anyone know how to match a random string and then remove and re-occurences of the same string on each line in a file.

Essentially I have a file:

```
00101  blah 0000202 thisisasentencethisisasentence 99929
00102  blah 0000202 thisisasentenc1thisisasentenc1 999292
```

I want to remove the duplicate sentence so it returns:

```
00101  blah 0000202 thisisasentence 99929
00102  blah 0000202 thisisasentenc1 999292
```

The width isn't fixed or anything like that.

I think this is close but I don't understand regex well and it highlights everything in the file except the last line - correctly finding the duplicate but only once.
    [Removing duplicate strings/words(not lines) using RegEx(notepad++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302308/removing-duplicate-strings-wordsnot-lines-using-regexnotepad)

Note I can also use the following to identify which parts of each line is duplicated - it highlights the duplicated values (thisisasentencethisisasentence) but I don't know how to split it

```
(.{5,})\1
```

Any help would be appreciated,
thanks.

EDIT I can reformat to create comma delimited (to some extent): (note with this, there is a chance a comma exists in the duplicated string but don't worry about that)

```
00101,blah,0000202,thisisasentencethisisasentence,99929
00102,blah,0000202,thisisasentenc1thisisasentenc1,999292
```

Comment: is the duplicate string always in the fourth column?

Comment: no note always but It is always after the thid comma (edited the above to show this)

Comment: Ah, I probably didn't make that clear - it only highlights the section that is duplicated - using $1 simply replaces what's there with itself (both sentences)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern in notepad++ with an empty string as replacement:

```
^(?>\S+[^\S\n]+){3,}?(\S+?)\K\1(?!\S)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/oM1xS1/1)

pattern details:

```
^        # anchors for the start of the line (by default in notepad++)
(?>            # atomic group: a column and the following space
    \S+          # all that is not a white-space character 
    [^\S\n]+     # white-spaces except newlines
){3,}?         # repeat 3 or more times (non-greedy) until you find
(\S+?)\K\1(?!\S)  # a column with a duplicate
```

details of the last subpattern:

```
(\S+?)   # capture one or more non-white characters
         # (non-greedy: until \1(?!\S) succeeds)
\K       # discard all previous characters from whole match result
\1       # back-reference to the capture group 1
(?!\S)   # ensure that the end of the column is reached
```

Note: using `{5,}` instead of `+` in `\S+?` (so `\S{5,}?`) is a good idea, if you are sure that columns contain at least five characters.

Comment: So close, and it works for a bunch but can it be extended to account for spaces in the string like "this is a sentence this is a sentence" - thanks though.  I maybe able to get by with the above.

Comment: @n34_panda: are the columns delimited by tabs?

Comment: No unfortunately not - I am essentially downloading data from a website as a string and trying to format it into an import file.  I can easily add comma's  to seperate out fields, if I do this then the duplicates will always be in the 4th column (see the edit in the question) this was  not displayed in the question originally...Its a ork in progress

Comment: You've probably aleady done enough, don't worry about me confusing it with commas or spaces...It's helped a bunch already

Comment: @n34_panda: The main problem with this kind of pattern is only the algorithmic complexity. You can modify it to fit better your requirements, but keep in mind to be as restrictive as possible. A chance, the size is limited because the duplicate and the original are on the same line and consecutives and there are always a white-space (or the end of the string) after the duplicate and before the original.

Comment: I'll take a look at trying to simplify the import, if I can stop the duplicates it does solve my problem.... I appreciate the help - thanks.

Comment: @n34_panda: You can handle the two cases with this pattern: `^(?>\S+[^\S\n]+){3,}?((?>\S+[^\S\n]+)*?(?:\S+\h+?|\S+?))\K\1(?:(?<=\s)|(?!\S))` https://regex101.com/r/dI3hK3/1

Answer (score 0):

You say you are happy with what `(.{5,})\1` matches. So, just use `$1` as the replacement value. It will automatically replace the repeated part and its copy with a single copy of the text.